# PhoneGap and Zxing QrCode - building issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, qr-code, zxing

I currently encounter a problem with installing ZXingWidget for a
PhoneGap project.
I followed both "PhoneGap Plugins" and ZXingWidget installation
guides, but my project building fails.
Most of my errors (17) look like that :

- path/project/Plugins/BarcodeScanner.mm:8:0 In file included from
  path/project/Plugins/BarcodeScanner.mm
- path/project/Plugins/BarcodeScanner.h:11:0   In file included from
  path/project/Plugins/BarcodeScanner.h
- ../zxing-1.6/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes/QRCodeReader.h:10:0 In file
  included from ../zxing-1.6/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes/QRCodeReader.h
- ../zxing-1.6/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes/FormatReader.h:22:0 Zxing/
  common/Counted.h: No such file or directory in ../zxing-1.6/iphone/
  ZXingWidget/Classes/FormatReader.h

That's mean my PhoneGap project finds "BarcodeScanner.mm",
"BarcodeScanner.h" and "QRCodeReader.h" but it is not able to reach
"FormatReader.h" ?
I check again and again the installation guides step by step, I think
I put well the relative path to ZXingWidget classes in the Project
Settings, but I don't understand where I'm wrong.

I will appreciate any help.

**SOLUTION**

I forgot to include the Zxing cpp source in the PhoneGap project.
As the "zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes" directory, the "cpp/core/src/" directory has to be included (the "recursive search" box doesn't need to be checked.)
In addition, the following iOS frameworks: AVFoundation, AudioToolbox, CoreVideo, CoreMedia and libiconv have to be added to the project.

Better explanations :
http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README%3Fspec%3Dsvn1651%26r%3D1651

Comment: So this phoneGap solution is working for you?

Comment: go ahead and write your solution as the answer to your question.

Comment: Please move your solution down to an answer so we can get this off the unanswered list.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION** as posted by craymond.

I forgot to include the Zxing cpp source in the PhoneGap project. As the "zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes" directory, the "cpp/core/src/" directory has to be included (the "recursive search" box doesn't need to be checked.) In addition, the following iOS frameworks: AVFoundation, AudioToolbox, CoreVideo, CoreMedia and libiconv have to be added to the project.

Better explanations : http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README%3Fspec%3Dsvn1651%26r%3D1651